# Hovering on text to open image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I would like to open a image when I hover on a word "PIC" but I have on the same section 10 or more of this & each of them must show the specific image of the element of the PIC.

```
<h6 id="pic1" class="pic"> PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic1" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><imgsrc="img/image1.jpg"/></div>

<h6 id="pic2" class="pic"> PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic2" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/image2.jpg"/>/div>

<h6 id="pic3" class="pic"> PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic3" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/image3.jpg"/>/div>
```

ect.....

```
<script>
$('h6.pic').mouseenter(function(){
$('div.img_pic').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
$('div.img_pic').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Thhis work fine but it open all the images instead to open only the image of the PIC I hovered ?
Any help will be appreciate. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
   $('h6.pic').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
       }).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).next().fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RgdnS/)

Also you are not closing you div properly

```
<img src="img/image2.jpg"/>/div>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ2fp/)

If that's the case then you can try this

```
$('h6.pic').mouseenter(function() {
        console.log($(this).next('div'))
        $(this).next().next('.imgpic').fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).next().next('.imgpic').fadeOut();
    });​
```

// OR

```
$('h6.pic').mouseenter(function() {
            console.log($(this).next('div'))
            $(this).next().next().fadeIn();
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).next().next().fadeOut();
        });​
```

Comment: I have a slight problem yet, when I add a line between the PIC & the image it don't work anymore do you know a way around that? If I put the line for the price under the line of image the price go under the image instead to stay in front of model #:1                                          <h6 class="alignleft">Model #: 1</h6>
<h6 id="pic1" class="pic">PIC</h6>
<h6 class="alignright">$1.00</h6>   
<div id="img_pic1" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/tabs_example_3_big.jpg"/></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>                                        Sorry & thank you

Comment: If that's the case you need to find the div with .imgpic class.. Check my updated code above

Comment: Thank you for your update. I tried the both but they didn't work, & my editor give me a error message: 'statement expected' after the last semi-colon on either updated version. What I do wrong? Your example in Fiddle work fine!

Comment: There might be empty space after the semicolon in the final statement. Check that and try again..

Comment: You are right, a space was in here when I removed your code make it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $(this) - refers to current element - 
and [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) - the element right after the current element

```
$('h6.pic').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next('div.imgpic').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).next('div.imgpic').fadeOut();
});
```

You also had a typo in your selector

```
$('div.img_pic') // <-- your class is imgpic without the _
```

Comment: <h6 class="alignleft">Model #:1 /h6>
<h6 id="pic1" class="pic">PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic1" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/tabs_example_3_big.jpg"/></div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using the `$(this).next()` approach is a bit inflexible; I'd approach it slightly differently by attaching a `data-*` attribute that points to the target pic of each of the heading elements:

```
<h6 id="pic1" class="pic" data-target="img_pic1"> PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic1" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/image1.jpg"/></div>

<h6 id="pic2" class="pic" data-target="img_pic2"> PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic2" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/image2.jpg"/></div>

<h6 id="pic3" class="pic" data-target="img_pic3"> PIC</h6>
<div id="img_pic3" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/image3.jpg"/></div>​
```

Then your jQuery'd look like this:

```
$('h6.pic').each(function () {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(this).mouseenter(function () {
    $('#' + target).fadeIn();
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    $('#' + target).fadeOut();
  });         
});​
```

What the heck, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/z9hvh/).
​

Comment: I tried but don't work, & my editor said: 'statement expected' after the last semi-colon on either version fiddle or above. It is frustrating because this same more interesting. Could you give me some pointer. Thank you,

Comment: Update: I need to add a line between the PIC line & the image line.                                             <h6 class="alignleft">Model #: 1</h6>
<h6 id="pic1" class="pic">PIC</h6>
<h6 class="alignright">$1.00</h6>   
<div id="img_pic1" class="imgpic" style="display:none"><img src="img/tabs_example_3_big.jpg"/></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>                                        Sorry to bother & thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you I find the problem, I thing a trailing space was after the last semicolon. Your code is excellent.

Comment: Yeah, I think there was a trailing newline there or something that jshint doesn't like. Also re having to add a line, that's why I said the `next()` approach is too inflexible, it ties you to a rigid structure.